# sed print from match until other match NOT inclusive

Tags: regex, sed

I want to print all lines from a match up to a second match, not including that second match.

What I have so far does everything and does too much, in that it prints the second match as well.

Specifically, let's say I want to print everything starting on a line containing 'test', up to, but not including, the first line starting with a number or an open bracket '['.

This goes some way, but not all the way:

```
sed -n '/test/,/^[0-9]\|^\[/p' file
```

Comment: grep -o -P might do the trick, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512398/capturing-parts-of-terminal-output-awk-or-sed/24513279#24513279

Comment: with sed version ? GNU sed allow a OR `|` but not posix version ?

Comment: I am coming late to the party, but you could pipe the command to `head -n-1` to remove the last line, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to do this via `awk`:

```
awk '/test/{p=1} /^([0-9]|\[)/{p=0} p' file
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks! Not familiar with awk: is there a way to search backwards with awk? Saying from that same match of 'test' backwards to first occurrence of a line starting with number or bracket.

Comment: Hmm searching backward is possible in `awk` but it is not straight forward as awk processes input line by line from top to bottom. To process bottom up one needs to store all lines in memory and process them in `END` block.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'p && /^[0-9]|^\[/ { exit }; /test/{ p = 1 } p' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat temp.txt
4
1
2
3
4
5
$ awk 'p && /4/ { exit }; /2|1/{ p = 1 } p' temp.txt
1
2
3
```

Notice how it skipped `4` when `/2|1/` wasn't found yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/test/,/^[0-9[]/ {
   /test/ {
      h;b
      }
   x;p
   $ {
     x
     /^[^0-9[]/ p
     }
   }' YourFile
```

should work but not elegant